# Gradle 'Android' project refresh failed (Error:Connection refused: connect)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on a application behind a firewall.

I have download permission using proxy. Proxy is set for application in gradle.properties as:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=abc
systemProp.http.proxyHost=10.120.0.20
systemProp.http.proxyUser=myusername
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

If I try the download than its fine. But if I try to sync application following error comes in android studio -

```
Gradle 'Android' project refresh failed 
Error:Connection refused: connect
```

My android studio is ver- 2.3.2
and dependencies is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
```

I don't know what to do, please help

Comment: Syncing and downloading aren't really different, so it seems to be a connection error in your proxy

Comment: Android studio is not using proxy in case of sync it directly hit firewall but in case of sdk download it is working fine.